# Skip match if in specific context

Tags: php, regex

The regex pattern is required to match all instances of a specified word, that does not need to match only individual words but also in-word content.

E.g.  searching for `media` match the instance in `mediator`.

There are few exceptions. If the word content is within a url or a font-family declaration the match should SKIP. This is the code i came up so far, but i'am missing something as it skips all.

```
(?:font-family:|https?:\/\/)[^\s\'";}]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)(media)
```

The above can be [tested at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5CX3Ea/2/).

Comment: Please include a sample of text from which you are trying to extract the matches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please see the url

Comment: You need a `|` after SKIP FAIL and perhaps also match media on the left side to make sure it is part of the font-family or https? `(?:font-family:\s*|https?:\/\/)[^\s'";}]*\bmedia\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bmedia\b` See https://regex101.com/r/HCZ473/1 but I am not sure this will cover all the ways you might specify `font-family:`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks so much for your help, obviously i omited the | operator.
I come up with this regex https://regex101.com/r/5CX3Ea/3/  but it still catch the "font-family: media"

Comment: @kole23 Did you try this pattern? https://regex101.com/r/jAjmUK/1 There are 1+  spaces after font-family:

Comment: Looks like you want to [skip the stuff inside braces](https://regex101.com/r/5CX3Ea/4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a pipe after `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and there is a space after `font-family:`

Note that you don't have to escape the `\'` in the character class and if you change the delimiter to something else than `/` you also don't have to escape those. You can also omit the capturing group around media.

```
(?:font-family:\h*|https?:\/\/)[^\s'";}]*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bmedia\b
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `font-family:\h*` Match `font:family:` and 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `https?:\/\/` Match http and optional s
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[^\s'";}]*` Match 0+ times any char except `'";` or a whitespace char
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` Consume and avoid using [SKIP and FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)
- `|` Or
- `\bmedia\b` Match media between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ece5kA/1)